# Schedule & Backup SharePoint 2013 automatically

Tags: 2013, backup

I am running MS Sharepoint 2013 on a Windows Server 2008.
Normally, I use HP Data Protector to backup all my stuff. I tried to backup my SharePoint 2013 with DP and it looks like it didn't work...

I have to choose another way.

I found there is a way to take a backup manually in Sharepoint 2013. It worked perfectly.

I searched a lot but I can't find a way to schedule a backup. I would like to get my backup automaticallly every weeks.

Which way would you recommend me?

Comment: You should still be able to back up all of your content databases as well as your configuration DB directly through your SQL server. I don't have SSMS in front of me but I'm almost positive you can schedule DB backups as well. If you've backed up everything, restoring should be a simple (read: not so simple) matter of restoring all of those DBs to a new SQL instance and then adding servers to it using the configuration wizard.

Comment: Thanks you very much John. 
I appreciate your help!
But how can I backup all files and the SQL DBs ? 
I know I can schedule a SQL backup of my DBs but how can I backup all files on the site ? 

Thanks again for your great help

Answer (score 5):

If you are talking about scheduling a SharePoint backup, you can use PowerShell and Task Scheduler.  The article below gives detailed instructions on how you can set that up.

[SharePoint 2013 Backup with PowerShell and Task Scheduler for beginners](http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2013/02/23/sharepoint-2013-backup-with-powershell-and-task-scheduler-for-beginners.aspx)